# Notify that the call is being recorded

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-programmable-voice

Currently I am able to record a live call using REST API.But I want to play an audio ("saying that the call is being recorded") whenever caller taps on record button and obviously the caller and the callee both will be able to hear that audio.
Record a live call code

```
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken, { accountSid: subaccountSid });
client.calls(callSid)
    .recordings
    .create()
    .then(function(recording){
    callback(null, recording);
});
```

And making a call

```
 const response = new VoiceResponse();

 const dial = response.dial({
    callerId: fromNumber,
 });
 dial.number(to);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but you will want to set-up the calls in a conference to begin with, then use the conference announcements to do this, as you need to be able to mix in this media into the conversation.

[Twilio Conference now supports Announcements](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/07/twilio-conference-now-supports-announcements.html)